# Formatting Printing in Loops

Tags: python, loops, data-structures, format

I have this code to create multiple rows of data through running a loop:

```html
import math
x = 65
y = 123
curRow = 0
curCol = 0
maxCol = 2
rows = math.ceil((y-x)/maxCol)
while curRow < rows:
   curCol = 0
   printRow = ""
   while curCol < maxCol:
       if x < 100:
           char = (chr(x))
           numb = ord(char)
           hexi = format(ord(char), 'x')
           printRow +=  (str(numb)).ljust(1) + hexi.rjust(9) + str(char).rjust(10) + ''.rjust(10)
       elif x >= 100:
           char = (chr(x))
           numb = ord(char)
           hexi = format(ord(char), 'x')
           printRow +=   str(numb).ljust(1) + hexi.rjust(7) + str(char).rjust(10)+ ''.rjust(10)


       x += 1
       curCol += 1
   print(printRow)
   curRow += 1
```

but the last three rows do not justify properly and end up like:

```html
65       41         A          66       42         B          
67       43         C          68       44         D          
69       45         E          70       46         F          
71       47         G          72       48         H          
73       49         I          74       4a         J          
75       4b         K          76       4c         L          
77       4d         M          78       4e         N          
79       4f         O          80       50         P          
81       51         Q          82       52         R          
83       53         S          84       54         T          
85       55         U          86       56         V          
87       57         W          88       58         X          
89       59         Y          90       5a         Z          
91       5b         [          92       5c         \          
93       5d         ]          94       5e         ^          
95       5f         _          96       60         `          
97       61         a          98       62         b          
99       63         c          100     64         d          
101     65         e          102     66         f          
103     67         g          104     68         h          
105     69         i          106     6a         j          
107     6b         k          108     6c         l          
109     6d         m          110     6e         n          
111     6f         o          112     70         p          
113     71         q          114     72         r          
115     73         s          116     74         t          
117     75         u          118     76         v          
119     77         w          120     78         x          
121     79         y          122     7a         z
```

How would I make it so all of the lines properly justify and end up straight.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the 9 with an 8:

```
printRow +=  (str(numb)).ljust(1) + hexi.rjust(8) + str(char).rjust(10) + ''.rjust(10)
```

Answer (score 0):

you give the wrong just width, when x > 100, it's width change from 2 to 3, but the `hexi.rjust` you drop from 9 to 7.  you can specify a higher just minimum width, so it looks pretty. like this:

`printRow +=  (str(numb)).ljust(4) + hexi.rjust(8) + str(char).rjust(10) + ''.rjust(10)`